# How to connect to a specific Wi-Fi band (2.4 GHz or 5 GHz) or channel from wpa_cli or wpa_supplicant in Linux?

Tags: linux, wireless-networking, wpa-supplicant

I am using the Wi-Fi chip on my board. I've successfully connected to Wi-Fi in the 2.4 GHz band, but for the 5 GHz Wi-Fi band I need to select the channel or band before connecting.

What extra arguments need to be given to the `wpa_cli` or `wpa_supplicant` utility so that it will connect to only the 5 GHz Wi-Fi band?

Comment: Set the 2.4ghz SSID different from the 5.0 Ghz SSID.

Comment: same ssid will work on 5Ghz and as well as on 2.4 Ghz. SO need to differentiate before connecting, so that it will connect to only 5GHz.

Comment: I am suggesting you make them different.  But how you force your adapter to connect at 5 ghz to a dual band network depends on the network adapter in question.

Answer (score 1):

Tobi's answer is almost correct but they're the wrong way around, `freq_list` can be set outside the network block, but `scan_freq` can't: https://w1.fi/cgit/hostap/tree/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf#n861

Comment: you're right, doesn't make sense to limit the frequencies inside a network block...

Comment: it's fixed now, thx

Answer (score 1):

You can limit the allowed frequencies in wpa_supplicant.conf:

add this outside of the network block:

freq_list=5500 5520 ... (all frequencies allowed in your country and in the desired band)

or you can also limit the scanned frequencies for a specific network (results in faster scans). Add to the config, inside the network block:

scan_freq=5500 5520 ...